# Typescript named import not transpiled correctly - TypeError xxx is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm giving Typescript a shot for a small project and I either don't have the right tsconfig setup or Typescript is just transpiling in a manner different than I'm used to in the babel.js world.

myPackage is an npm library. both the npm lib and the client project are meant to run under nodejs 8.x using all the latest bells and whistles.

myPackage - index.ts:

```
export { default as updateTaskLog } from './updateTaskLog';
export { default as saveGitEvent } from './saveGitEvent';
```

myPackage transpiled:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var updateTaskLog_1 = require("./updateTaskLog");
exports.updateTaskLog = updateTaskLog_1.default;
var saveGitEvent_1 = require("./saveGitEvent");
exports.saveGitEvent = saveGitEvent_1.default;
```

clienProject - run.ts:

```
import {
  saveGitEvent,
  updateTaskLog,
} from 'myPackage';
```

run.js transpiled:

```
const myPackage_1 = require("myPackage"); // what? why is a destructured import transpiled to this?

...
const eventId = await myPackage_1.saveGitEvent(event); // TypeError: myPackage_1.saveGitEvent is not a function
```

both projects use the exact same tsconfig.json setup:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "preserveSymlinks": false,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Why is Typescript transpiling destructed named imports to a single variable?

Any suggestions for getting this to transpile and run correctly?

Comment: "Why is Typescript transpiling destructed named imports to a single variable?" it kind of doesn't matter because you don't get a smaller bundle with commonjs anyway

Comment: The transpilation of run.js is correct, since you’re targeting CommonJS modules. The issue would appear to be with `myPackage`. How have you declared the dependency? EDIT: Is `myPackage` targeting ES6 modules?

Comment: I would check what `myPackage_1` equals to in a debugger and then it shall be clear what to do